# Trying to output 0 1 2 3 8 5 6 14 8 9 using a for loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

This is what I have so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i<= 9; i++){
            int output = i;
            if (i % 4 == 0){
                output *= 2;
            }
            System.out.print(output + " ");
        }
```

and it outputs this:

```
0 1 2 3 8 5 6 7 16 9
```

I'm not sure why it's multiplying the 8 and not the 7 like I want it to do.
It's supposed to output this:

```
0 1 2 3 8 5 6 14 8 9
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Because 7 is not divisible by 4? Both 4 and 8 are divisible by 4.

Comment: when i == 7, i % 4 != 0 so it won't double it.  But it will double the 8.

Comment: "Supposed to" based on what? Appears you only need to check `i == 4 || i == 7`, not use a modulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i<= 9; i++){
       int output = i;
       if (i == 4 || i ==7){  // <-- when to double the value       
                output *= 2;
        }
        System.out.print(output + " ");
}
```